# Convert PivotItem into Usercontrol to improve loading performance in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My MainPage.xaml is a pivot page with 3 PivotItems. Currently it is loading all of the necessary stuff for each of the PivotItems on the MainPage constructor. This is bad because it loads a lot of stuff that are not necessary.

Reading [here](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2011/08/12/Windows-Phone-Pivot-and-loading-content.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941101%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) suggests that I only load the first PivotItem and after it loads, load the rest of the items. Specifically :

> Improve the performance of the pivot application by loading Pivot control content on-demand as opposed to loading everything at startup. One solution is to take the content from each PivotItem control and convert into UserControls. You can then subscribe to the LoadingPivotItem event on the root pivot control. Next, in the event handler, instantiate the proper UserControl and set it as the PivotItem content.

If I follow the suggestion:

```
private void OnLoadingPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.Content != null)
{
    // Content loaded already
    return;
}

Pivot pivot = (Pivot)sender;

if (e.Item == pivot.Items[0])
{
    e.Item.Content = new Page1Control();
}
else if (e.Item == pivot.Items[1])
{
    e.Item.Content = new Page2Control();
}
else if (e.Item == pivot.Items[2])
{
    e.Item.Content = new Page3Control();
}
}
```

I should use create class PageXControl ? Should it inherit somehow from main-page class ?

How do i take the content from each PivotItem control and convert into UserControls ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own Pivot items, which would inherit from PivotItem. I have put together a sample, based on the default Pivot project in VS, which splits out the two Pivot items into their own classes :-

http://www.smartmobiledevice.co.uk/projects/PivotItemUserControlSample.zip

Comment: thanks. I have noticed you used `PivotItem` for the pivot pages code instead of `UserControl`. is there any difference ?

Comment: I think that you would use a UserControl if you were putting a number of controls together to form another control, however as you are only interested in the PivotItem then it makes sense to derive from that.

Answer (score 10):

Extracting the content of your PivotItems into UserControls is actually very simple. First, create a new UserControl for each of your PivotItems. Then move the content of the PivotItems from the PivotItem into the UserControls. Then you create the controls in the `OnLoadingPivotItem` method as you specified. I have a created a small project on GitHub to show you how to do this. See: https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/pivotcontentdemo

As you can see, I derived the UserControls from a base class as they are semantically the same. However, this is by no means necessary, it is fine to just inherit from UserControl.

I prefer this approach over the approach where the PivotItems themselves are extracted into custom controls.