# Adding xaml page as Pivot Item

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have two xaml page, PageOne.xaml and PageTwo.xaml. Each xaml has its own code behind PageOne.xaml.cs and PageTwo.xaml.cs running different logic.

Now, I wish to create a Pivot Control, adding two Xaml pages above as Pivot Item in C# code.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Simply convert **PageOne** and **PageTwo** into `UserControls` then set the `PivotItem.Content` to the `UserControls`.

[This related question discuses lazy-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373012/convert-pivotitem-into-usercontrol-to-improve-loading-performance-in-wp7) of the `UserControls` for performance reasons.

[Caliburn Micro](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Caliburn.Micro), an MVC-like framework for Windows Phone and Windows 8, has a [built in helper which automatically handles PivotItems](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/first-steps-with-caliburn-micro-in-windows-phone-8-pivot/) like this.

Comment: Thanks Neil, are you able to solve my issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745852/systemtray-for-pivot-item-content

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A `PhoneApplicationPage` can be hosted only in a `PhoneApplicationFrame`. You will need to transfer your two pages layout into the Pivot control, in different PivotItems.

Comment: how about the CS code for PageOne and PageTwo? does they need to fit in Pivot.xaml.cs too?

Comment: If you have code in your Page's code behind .cs file yes, you should transfer it. Like Neil Turner said, you could convert your pages to `UserControls` and with minor modifications achieve what you want without transfering all your xaml layout from the two pages to the PivotItems.