# SystemTray for Pivot Item content

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Pivot Control in MainPage.xaml page. I add in the PageOne.xaml.cs as pivot item using

```
private void OnLoadingPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.Content != null)
{
    // Content loaded already
    return;
}

Pivot pivot = (Pivot)sender;

if (e.Item == pivot.Items[0])
{
    e.Item.Content = new PageOne();
}
}
```

Thing is not working so fine, but I have tried to fix them, for example,

```
    // NavigationService.Navigation(new Uri());
    // need to change to
    (App.Current as App).RootFrame.Navigate( new Uri());

// ApplicationBar for PivotItem
appBar = ((PhoneApplicationPage)((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content).ApplicationBar;
```

Now, I need to show ProgressIndicator on my PivotControl MainPage.xaml from my PageOne.xaml.cs code.

```
_progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator
            {
                IsIndeterminate = true,
                IsVisible = false,
            };

            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, _progressIndicator);
```

But progressIndicator doesn't show, what should I do? My guess is to call the SystemTray of RootFrame but I am not sure how to.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the property `IsVisible` to `true`.

Wish this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I need to pass MainPage as reference to PageOne, and put it as parameter when using SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator.

In MainPage.xaml.cs

```
e.Item.Content = new PageOne(this);
```

Here is the constructor code from PageOne.xaml.cs

```
public PageOne(MainPage page) {
_progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator
            {
                IsIndeterminate = true,
                IsVisible = false,
            };
SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(page, _progressIndicator);
}
```